# replace jQuery animation with built in angular animation

Tags: angularjs, animation

Given this template:

```
<div fade>
    <h2>
    TEST {{ headline.Title }}
    </h2>
</div>
```

And the following directive:
How do I change this directive to **replace** the **jquery** fade with built in **angular** animations?

*I require the text to fade out, get replaced, and then fade in.*

```
newman.directive('fade', ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.index = 0;
        $scope.news = $interval(function () {
            // REPLACE JQUERY BELOW
            $(element).fadeOut('fast', function() {                    
                $scope.index = $scope.getValidNewHeadlineIndex();
                // view is currently correctly updated by the line below.
                $scope.headline = $scope.headlines[$scope.index];
                $(element).fadeIn('slow'); // REPLACE JQUERY HERE TOO!
            });
        }, 10000);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: did you add ng-animate to the angular.module?

Comment: I have altered the question to be more concise (I hope). Using a jQuery example that can be altered to use CSS / AngularJS. There are a few examples around, but none I can find that squeeze a view change between two animations. Fade out, change view, fade in...

Comment: I had really hoped this would be snatched up and answered quickly. Does anyone have some suggestions on editing the question to make it more attractive to the experienced angularjs coders out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Figured it out, mostly...*

This is for anyone else battling with angular-js animation. A working [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/JFjwo).

The basic procedure is to create some CSS to create the animation, and add a call to `$animate.enter(...` to the `'fade'` directive.

`$animate.leave` doesn't seem to be required. I will add more detail when I know more.

#### the modified directive:

```
app.directive('fade', ['$animate', '$interval', function($animate, $interval) {
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $interval(function () {
            $animate.enter(element, element.parent());
            $scope.headline = $scope.next();            
            /* $animate.leave(element); */ // not required?
      }, 6000);
    }
}]);
```

#### the style sheet entries:

```
.fade {
    transition: 2s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
}
.fade.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### alternate solution, using TweenMax

This solution is suitable for (you guessed it - internet explorer < 10)
[TweenMax solution using onComplete.](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/vdwsj)

```
app.directive('fade', ['$animate', '$interval', function($animate, $interval) {
    var fadeOut = function(target, done){
        TweenMax.to(
            target, 0.2,/*{'opacity':'1',ease:Ease.linear},*/
                {'opacity':'0',ease:Ease.linear, onComplete:done });
        };

    var fadeInUp = function(target){
                        var tl = new TimelineMax();
                        tl.to(target,0,{'opacity':'0',top:'+=50'})
                    .to(target,1,{'opacity':'1',top:'-=50',ease:Quad.easeOut});
        }; 
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {              
      $interval(function () {
            fadeOut(element, function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.headline = $scope.next();            
                  fadeInUp(element);                
              });
          });
      }, 4000);
    }
}]);
```