# Angular - how to replace this jQuery state change with correct Angular code?

Tags: jquery, angular, sass, css-animations, keyframe

In a component I have a subject that fires a `.next(value)` and it triggers this jQuery logic:

```
  if (this.isOpen) {
    jQuery(`#preview-${this.index}`).
      stop().slideDown('fast');
  } else {
    jQuery(`#preview-${this.index}`).
      stop().css('display', 'block').slideUp('fast');
  };
```

You can see it is targeting an id, so I know that I have to replace that with a `@ViewChild` decorator construct.

How do I use @ViewChild in combination with scss keyframes to achieve the same functionality so I can remove the JQuery.

Since this is a very simple CSS transition, I am looking for a way to do this without having to use the angular animation library (unless that is the only way of course).

Note
I found the identical problem asked and answered for AngularJS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850066/replace-jquery-animation-with-built-in-angular-animation), but not Angular (yet anyway!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues in making this work:

1. Notice that at the end the code is applying 'display:none' to hide the element. jQuery applies that after the animation ends. So the problem here is that you cannot animate a display:none (obviously, as there is nothing there!). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278600/how-to-use-displaynone-on-the-end-of-a-css-animation) helped me understand this.
2. The jQuery slidedown is simply animating the height of the element, bringing it to 0.

So with that knowledge it became quite easy. First set up the two states with css classes and the animation:

```
.fb-card-open {
  display: block;
}
.fb-card-closed {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: slideup;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes slideup {
  0% { height:inherit; }
  100% { height:0; }
}
```

This means we have the open state and the closed state at 100%, which basically sets the height to 0 and removes padding top and bottom (since there is padded text inside the animated element so even with height 0, you would still see some vertical space)

Then use [ngClass] directive to switch between the two classes:

```
[ngClass]="{'fb-card-open': isOpen, 'fb-card-closed' : !isOpen }"
```

Thanks to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/) which helped understand how to do this (the article is about AngularJS, not Angular, but the principle is the same as the [ngClass] directive behaves the same way)

**Note**
If you set the padding:0 instead of just top and bottom, you get a cool 'fly-in' effect for the children of the element, which is kind of a nifty bonus I found by doing this!